# St_perimeter in the SF library in R

Tags: r, area, r-sf

I can't get st_perimeter to work.

Comment: one function with same name is in [ggRaver](https://rdrr.io/github/ggRaver/Lslide/man/st_perimeter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first try

```
library(lwgeom) #Check if is installed.
```

Also, notice that you should have your file in the right EPSG